# Efficient Prime Factorization Algorithm with List of Prime Numbers

Tags: algorithm, prime-factoring

I am trying to implement an efficient algorithm, that can find the prime factorization for a given number n. I also have a list of all prime numbers up to at least n.

An example: If I have a number n = 50, the result should be: 2, 5, 5.

My ideas so far:

1. Check if n == 1, if true return 1
2. Check if n == 2, if true return 2

If both 1. and 2. are false:

3. Divide n by 2 as often as possible and add 2 to the vector of results
4. Try to find the (possibly by 2 divided) n in the list of prime numbers.
5. If n is in the list, add it to the results and return the results.
6. Find the largest prime number in the list, that is smaller than n.
7. Divide by the prime number found in step 6. If division without rest is possible, add the prime number to the results.
8. Check if n==1 and return the result if true
9. Repeat the steps 5-9.

Is that algorithm efficient or do you have any ideas for improvement?

Comment: OK, your algorithm sounds reasonable.  Now what is the question?

Comment: 1 is not a prime number.

Comment: if you already have the list up to `n` you already know if `n` is prime. Do you mean a list up to `n/2` / `sqrt(n)` / some other `m < n`  ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clearer. I am not sure if that algorithm is really efficient and if I made proper use of the list of prime numbers.

Comment: No, the list of all prime numbers goes all the way up to n. But the point is not knowing if n is a prime number, but getting the prime decomposition/factorization. E.g. 6 = 2 * 3.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I want to implement the algorithm using C++. But you are probably right, I should remove that tag.

Comment: The answer from [btilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585411) covers the algorithm.  Implementation-wise: (1) having the square of all the primes (as well) would save a multiply -- mind you, multiplies are generally so fast this might not be a big win; but (b) doing the division as a multiply will save cycles on most machines -- that requires the construction and storage of the magic multiplier and shift for each prime.  It kinda depends on how much you need to squeeze cycles out of this.  Pipelines being what they are, I wonder if trying the two next primes at the same time helps.

Comment: You mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed algorithm is inefficient.  You should divide not by the largest remaining prime, but by the smallest.  And if the smallest squared is larger than what is left, what is left is prime.

Your existing algorithm will need `O(n/log(n))` divisions on average.  My improvement makes it `O(sqrt(n)/log(n))` instead.  Which is still not a particularly efficient factorization algorithm.  But is fine out to a few million.

Comment: Thanks, I think this should suffice. Now that you mention it, I recall the rule with the squaring.